# Resource compilation error (Bad character in source input)

Tags: c++builder, embedded-resource, c++builder-2010

I have added text file with following content to the project:

```
1 24 "MyApplication.manifest"
```

In the same folder there is also `MyApplication.manifest` file which is XML - this one:
[C++ Builder / Delphi 2010 application manifest template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536779/c-builder-delphi-2010-application-manifest-template)

After I attempt to build resource from RC I get error - Bad character in source input(1)

Any ideas why?

`RT_MANIFEST` value is 24, but I am unsure what 1 is supposed to be.

Comment: `1` is the resource ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to find the answer myself so no answer necessary. The problem was, as usual very obscure.

Turned out that the resource script file (.RC) I was using had an UTF-8 byte order mark in the file (`0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`) which was invisible to the text editor but resource compiler complained about it. After removing the BOM resource compiled correctly.

I don't think many people fall into this trap but at least if anyone else sees this error in resource compiler, you should examine if there is an UTF-8 BOM in your file by viewing HEX-dump of RC file because `brcc32.exe` resource compiler seems to have issues with that.

Comment: submit a QC report if you haven't already -- even if they can't add support for UTF-8 source, they could at least give a useful error message.