# Delphi cannot execute brcc32 via shellexecute

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have started writing components and I want to write a program to generate DCR files for me. The picture of a component must be a 24x24 bitmap, so I need to create a resource file and then use `brcc32` to create the DCR.

Steps:

1. Create a 24x24 bitmap (Paint, old but gold)
2. Create the RC file
3. Create the DCR using brcc32

So, I want to write a program to make all this stuff for me and this is the form. Inside the edit fields I have written their `Name` property.

[image]

This is the code:

```
unit uBmp2rc;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.IOUtils,
  Vcl.ExtDlgs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, ShellApi;

type
  TBitmapConverter = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    edtClassName: TEdit;
    Label2: TLabel;
    edtSource: TEdit;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    edtDirectory: TEdit;
    OpenPicture: TOpenPictureDialog;
    Label5: TLabel;
    edtBitmap: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Label6: TLabel;
    Preview: TImage;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    path: string;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  BitmapConverter: TBitmapConverter;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TBitmapConverter.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

 if OpenPicture.Execute then
  begin
   edtBitmap.Text := OpenPicture.FileName;
   Preview.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenPicture.FileName);
  end;

end;

procedure TBitmapConverter.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var sw: TStreamWriter;
    tmpName, source, command: string;
begin

 path := edtDirectory.Text;
 source := edtSource.Text;

 tmpName := TPath.Combine(path, source+'.rc');
 Preview.Picture.SaveToFile(TPath.Combine(path, source + '.bmp'));

 sw := TStreamWriter.Create(tmpName, False, TEncoding.UTF8);
 try
  sw.Write(edtClassName.Text + ' BITMAP "' + source + '.bmp"');
 finally
  sw.Free;
 end;

 command := '/C brcc32 -fo"' + TPath.Combine(path, source) + '.dcr" "' + TPath.Combine(path, source) + '.rc"';
 ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar('cmd.exe'), PChar(command), nil, SW_HIDE);

end;

procedure TBitmapConverter.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 edtDirectory.Text := TPath.GetDocumentsPath;
end;
```

I can correctly create the RC file, but the DCR is not being created. Am I doing something wrong in the command?

I have added the `PChar()` after Googling this and I have found the hint on StackOverflow, but still I'm not sure.

Comment: Why don't you check for return errors? You probably need to specify the entire path to `brcc32.exe`. I also think the entire prologue is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Hmm I have a suspect that the problem is in your rc file. I'll reproduce your code and I'll check, I think that the UTF8 is not what you're looking for. There is something on google too about it

Comment: @kobik No it is not useless. The steps I have shown wth 1 2 3 are what I am doing in the Button2Click. That is to better understand since I see that people here complain about giving too few details

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi, Fair enough, But why wont you check for errors? The error (even from cmd.exe in the Windows shell itself, could have give a lead)

Comment: Raffaele to find the answer, as @kobik says, you could have checked the error. To find it I have simply saved an UTF8 rc and tested it with brcc32. It gave me the error "bad character in source input", I googled it and I found the solution (= UTF8 is bad, ANSI is good).

Comment: kobik and Alberto Miola: ok that's fine but at the beginning I didn't know that the error was in the stream writer. How could I have tested that? I had no idea about it!

Comment: Pointless to ask the shell to create a cmd process to create a brcc32 process. Call CreateProcess to create a brcc32 process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I create the image for my components I use notepad and I save the file as `filename.rc` with the default encoding (**ANSI**, not UTF8). You are using UTF8 and you should change:

```
sw := TStreamWriter.Create(tmpName, False, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

with this:

```
sw := TStreamWriter.Create(tmpName, False, TEncoding.ANSI);
```

If you use the ANSI encoding your program will work. Your command is correct; if you try to run `cmd.exe` and call the brcc32 with those parameters you'll see that the UTF8 encoding gives you an error. Instead, the ANSI encoding works perfectly and you'll have yout `*.drc` file ready to use.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538863/resource-compilation-error-bad-character-in-source-input) something similar, it's about c++ builder but it shows that the problem is related to the UTF8 encoding.

Comment: But what is the difference between ANSI and UTF8? How they store the characters?

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi google can fully answer your question

Comment: Ok. Anyway changing to ANSI solved my problem, thank you