# Why Screen.PrimaryScreen is not getting FullScreen?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

i was trying to get screenshot for the whole screen, but when i try to use Screen.PrimaryScreen it gets the screen right, but not the full screen. The strange part when i try to save the image i get, it's equal the resolution as my PC's resolution is. Here is the code :

```
            var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                                   Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            //Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
            var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

            //Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
            gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                        0,
                                        0,
                                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                        CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            bmpScreenshot.Save("New.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

As you can see it should work, but i got no idea why it doesn't get the complete Full Screen, Here is a picture :
[image: Problem's Picture]

Thanks.

Comment: I tested your code, seems to work just fine here.

Comment: What do you expect could be from then?
Also you tested it on which version of VS or NetFramework? @Jim

Comment: The version of VS should not matter, the target framework (maybe) if you are targeting an old one, you should mention it. *(I have tested this in 4.5.2)*

Comment: Nope, didn't use any old, also now i tried 4.0 , 4.5.2 , 4.6.1 , 3.5. No changes!

Comment: Look at this [Picture](http://image.prntscr.com/image/0bdb79854a9146a8b672da47fe77116b.png) @Jim

Comment: Your best shot is to investigate why `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.` doesn't give the correct information ... this can be due DPI scaling. I have found a topic that might be interesting to start for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987085/screen-resolution-not-matching-screen-bounds

Comment: Great, followed it and got it fixed! Thank you! (Although i though that after VS 2012, that done automated)

Comment: @GameHackerPM post your new findings as an answer and accept it.