# System.Drawing.Font Creation From SYSTEM_FONT Stock Object using System.Drawing.Font.FromHfont(IntPtr hfont)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, gdi

I'm trying to create an instance of System.Drawing.Font using the **SYSTEM_FONT** stock object using `System.Drawing.Font.FromHfont(IntPtr hfont)`, like so:

```
      static Font GetStockFont(StockObjects index)
      {
         Font returnFont = Font.FromHfont(GetStockObject(index));
         return returnFont;
      }

      [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
      static extern IntPtr GetStockObject(StockObjects fnObject);

      enum StockObjects 
      {
         WHITE_BRUSH = 0,
         LTGRAY_BRUSH = 1,
         GRAY_BRUSH = 2,
         DKGRAY_BRUSH = 3,
         BLACK_BRUSH = 4,
         NULL_BRUSH = 5,
         HOLLOW_BRUSH = NULL_BRUSH,
         WHITE_PEN = 6,
         BLACK_PEN = 7,
         NULL_PEN = 8,
         OEM_FIXED_FONT = 10,
         ANSI_FIXED_FONT = 11,
         ANSI_VAR_FONT = 12,
         SYSTEM_FONT = 13,
         DEVICE_DEFAULT_FONT = 14,
         DEFAULT_PALETTE = 15,
         SYSTEM_FIXED_FONT = 16,
         DEFAULT_GUI_FONT = 17,
         DC_BRUSH = 18,
         DC_PEN = 19
      }
```

But when I do I'm getting the following `System.ArgumentException` exception, is there something I'm missing? I was under the impression that GetStockObject in this case would return a proper HFont:

`Only TrueType fonts are supported. This is not a TrueType font.`

Comment: You can get a valid Font handle with `WHITE_BRUSH` (you'll get a default Font of a default size: 12 Points). `NULL_BRUSH` will give you the same default Font but in the smallest size available in a generic context, `1.5` Points. Some other stock objects (`LTGRAY_BRUSH`, `GRAY_BRUSH`, but not `BLACK_BRUSH`) will return the same hFont object. `DEFAULT_GUI_FONT` will return `Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25` Points. The others won't get you a compatible object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you may ignore:

> According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getstockobject#remarks): System font. By default, the system uses the system font to draw
>   menus, dialog box controls, and text. It is not recommended that you
>   use DEFAULT_GUI_FONT or SYSTEM_FONT to obtain the font used by dialogs
>   and windows; for more information, see the remarks section. The
>   default system font is Tahoma.

[An ancient document:](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=35013)

> Among the things you can get with the GetStockObject function are two
>   fonts called SYSTEM_FONT and DEFAULT_GUI_FONT. What are they?
>
> They are fonts nobody uses any more.
>
> Back in the old days of Windows 2.0, the font used for dialog boxes
>   was a bitmap font called System. This is the font that SYSTEM_FONT
>   retrieves, and it is still the default dialog box font for
>   compatibility reasons. Of course, nobody nowadays would ever use such
>   an ugly font for their dialog boxes. (Among other things, it’s a
>   bitmap font and therefore does not look good at high resolutions, nor
>   can it be anti-aliased.)
>
> DEFAULT_GUI_FONT has an even less illustrious history. It was created
>   during Windows 95 development in the hopes of becoming the new default
>   GUI font, but by July 1994, Windows itself stopped using it in favor
>   of the various fonts returned by the SystemParametersInfo function.
>   Its existence is now vestigial.
>
> **One major gotcha with SYSTEM_FONT and DEFAULT_GUI_FONT is that on a
>   typical US-English machine, they map to bitmap fonts that do not
>   support ClearType.**

If you want to use `DEFAULT_GUI_FONT`, you can refer [@RbMm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40342566/11128312), get `NONCLIENTMETRICS` by `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS)` and then use it `LOGFONT` data, for create self font. or you can query for `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETICONTITLELOGFONT)` and use it.

Hope to help you:)