# Configure manifest tool options using cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Is it possible to configure DPI Awareness value using cmake or some script?
 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySWvE.png]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the dpiAware property in a Windows application manifest to "per monitor" in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551112/how-can-i-set-the-dpiaware-property-in-a-windows-application-manifest-to-per-mo)

Comment: why is it duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this helpful. Applying manifest using cmake.

https://gist.github.com/bjornblissing/6fc452fe7ec1fdfe3419

Answer (score 4):

Create a manifest file (`.manifest` is important) with the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process

Then add it to your binary target in CMake using:

```
target_sources(your-binary PRIVATE path-to-the-file-above.manifest)
```

You'll need CMake 3.4 or newer, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/release/3.4.html#other

Answer (score 0):

There is no internal manifest support in CMake, but you can use it, there are couple of hints on this site (e.g. people using manifest e.g. because of UAC etc.).

About DPI, search other topic on SO e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551112/how-can-i-set-the-dpiaware-property-in-a-windows-application-manifest-to-per-mo)

Answer (score 0):

We can set the Manifest Tool -> Input and Output -> DPI Awareness in the Visual Studio target project properties:

[VS_DPI_AWARE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DPI_AWARE.html) in `CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_executable(myproject myproject.cpp)
set_property(TARGET myproject PROPERTY VS_DPI_AWARE "PerMonitor")
```

Valid values are `PerMonitor`, `ON`, or `OFF`.

Start in version 3.16.