# D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain does not swap to full screen on 2nd monitor

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, dxgi

The original problem that I ran into, was that I wasn't able to get my game to run in full screen on my 2nd monitor. Going to display settings and swapping main display from 2nd to 1st, lets my game run in full screen without any problems. The resolution on both of my monitors is identical so the problem has to be somewhere else.
[image: displays]

The code that is responsible for the full screen swap looks like this:

```
// create device and front/back buffers
if( FAILED( hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain( 
    nullptr,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    nullptr,
    createFlags,
    nullptr,
    0,
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &sd,
    &pSwapChain,
    &pDevice,
    nullptr,
    &pImmediateContext ) ) )
{
    throw CHILI_GFX_EXCEPTION( hr,L"Creating device and swap chain" );
}
```

while the swap chain description `sd` was previously created like this:

```
// create device and swap chain/get render target view
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd = {};
sd.BufferCount = 1;
sd.BufferDesc.Width = Graphics::ScreenWidth;
sd.BufferDesc.Height = Graphics::ScreenHeight;
sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 1;
sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 60;
sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
sd.OutputWindow = key.hWnd;
sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
sd.Windowed = !f;
sd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;
```

`f` is set to `true` and the code does exactly what I want it to do on monitor 1, however the window remains windowed on monitor 2. `hr` is also `S_OK` suggesting that everything went fine.

DXGI Reference says that:

> We recommend that you create a windowed swap chain and allow the end user to change the swap chain to full screen through IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreenState;

Quick modification to the code to set the full screen state with the swap chain method results in:

```
hr = pSwapChain->SetFullscreenState(TRUE, vOutput[0]);
```

The HRESULT `hr` says that the method failed with `E_FAIL`.

As an extra test, changing `vOutput[0]` to `vOutput[1]` makes my game work in full screen on another monitor without any problems.

Trying to find information about this led me to multiple steam forum posts where different users were experiencing same type of error when trying to go full screen in games like [Devil May Cry 4](https://steamcommunity.com/app/329050/discussions/0/361798516935633386/), [Company of Heroes 2](https://steamcommunity.com/app/231430/discussions/0/864971287463931409/) or [Resident Evil 5](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/resident-evil-5-pc-official-benchmark-and-release-date.99436/page-13). A thing that all of these posts had in common was that the game didn't run in full screen on 2nd monitor. From the information in these posts I also discovered that full screen will work if the screen resolution is set at 1680x1050 or lower.

This leads me to believe that the actual bug might be somewhere inside direct3D files, but where?

Why is `SetFullscreenState` returning `E_FAIL` and `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` does nothing and how can I make it work?

If it's not possible, what's a good replacement for the `SetFullscreenState` that achieves the same goal?

Comment: Could it be that you create window with default placement at primary display, then create swap chain and then try to move window on secondary display? The recommended way to create a swap chain is to create swap chain in windowed mode and then make it full screen on particular output by calling [`IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreenState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174579(v=vs.85).aspx) supplying pointer to desired DXGI Output.

Comment: I'm not sure how to identify which monitor is being used for the initial window creation, but the initial window spawns on monitor 2 even before swap chain. As for `pSwapChain->SetFullscreenState` - it always returns E_FAIL so I might need some help on setting that one up too.

Comment: Well, in order to create swap chain that can be switched between windowed / fullscreen mode you will need to specify `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH` flag. Also notice that `RefreshRate` that you are currently passing when creating swap chain (60 Hz) does not match actual display refresh rate (59 Hz) of the second display.

Comment: I have tried different refresh rates on both monitors with no success. As for swap chain flags - I'm using the framework code I'm not very familiar with how the DXGI interfaces work and msdn lacks examples so I'd appreciate an example from you.

Comment: I have now successfully managed to test `SetFullscreenSate` with both `IDXGIOutput` (one for montor 1 and one for monitor 2) and while the method returns `S_OK` for monitor 1, it fails with `E_FAIL` on monitor 2.

Comment: You might have an easier time figuring out what is going on by avoiding the legacy combo device and swapchain creation function and doing the individual steps. See [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/). There are some known issues trying to do FSE (fullscreen exclusive) with multiple devices at the same time if they are using different drivers.

Comment: I'll randomly guess that these monitors are operating at different DPI settings.  A feature available since Win8.1.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/23551112/17034

Comment: Just FYI, `DXGI_MODE_DESC::RefreshRate` measures hertz, so I'm going to guess that your numerator and denominator are backwards there.