# Control size changes when debugging high dpi winforms project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, highdpi

currently i am working on high dpi windows forms applications. I use a monitor with a 3840x2160 resolution and 150% scaling.

I took the [high dpi sample application](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-samples) from windows. I figured out that if i debug the sample application and set a breakpoint to the constructor head and add the `SystemFonts.DefaultFont` to the watchlist it destroys the layout. I have no idea why this happens.

[image: See windows sample application (1)]

[image: Breakpoint]

[image: Watchlist]

[image: Windows sample application (2)]

I hope I didn't forgot to mention anything important. Thanks in advance for your answers and help!

Comment: Have you modified the `app.manifest`, uncommenting the `<dpiAware />` section? Read [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e?answertab=active#tab-top) and [How can I set the dpiAware property in a Windows application manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551112/how-can-i-set-the-dpiaware-property-in-a-windows-application-manifest-to-per-mo).

Comment: Thanks. Now it works like it should. But I still don`t understand why the behaviour is like this if i debug. Do you have an explanation?