# How to disable the Windows DPI virtualization from c++ code?

Tags: c++, windows, sdk, virtualization, dpi

I want to disable completely the Windows DPI virtualization, but only for a particular application while it runs. The change should only affect the application lifetime.

In fact I want to reproduce the exact same effect as the following configuration, but without the user having to configure it manually (the below popup was get by right-clicking the .exe with the mouse, then selecting Properties):
[image]

Is there a way to do that from c++ code, using the Windows API?

Comment: [*Setting the default DPI awareness for a process*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/C9488338-D863-45DF-B5CB-7ED9B869A5E2)

Comment: Thank for the answer, unfortunately this does not work in my case. When I modify my manifest following the given instructions I get an "incorrect side-by-side" configuration error while opening my app. The system logs says me that "The element dpiAware appears as a child of element urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1^windowsSettings which is not supported by this version of Windows". I also tried several variants as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551112/how-can-i-set-the-dpiaware-property-in-a-windows-application-manifest-to-per-mo. But no way

Comment: this only say that you incorrect  write manifest. example of correct - https://pastebin.com/YfaDwAu0

Comment: Ok, it works now. Thanks for your help