# can't find correct application configuration file in WPF project

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm trying to enable the WebView control to appear properly on high DPI display. Following the instruction from here:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview#high-dpi

While I can't find where is the correct application configuration file to add the below code:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
   <windowsSettings>
     <!-- The combination of below two tags have the following effect :
     1) Per-Monitor for >= Windows 10 Anniversary Update
     2) System < Windows 10 Anniversary Update -->
     <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>
     <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true/PM</dpiAware>
   </windowsSettings>
 </application>
```

Right now I have a file named `App.config`, but I can't add the above code into it successfully. So where is that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place these settings in [application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests) file (`app.manifest`) instead of `app.config`, [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/PerMonitorDPI) github repo with samples contains step-by-step tutorial. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551112/how-can-i-set-the-dpiaware-property-in-a-windows-application-manifest-to-per-mo) thread also contains some samples

Comment: But the [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview#high-dpi) asks for entering that info in the `app.congfig` file. Is that incorrect info?

Comment: @nam [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/PerMonitorDPI#enabling-per-monitor-dpi-for-your-app) sample tells about `app.manifest`, the same is mentioned in this [msdn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/mt846517(v%3Dvs.85))